# SQL Recursive CTE Replacing records in each recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, replace

I have a table like this:

```
ItemID  ItemFormula
100     'ID_3+ID_5'
110     'ID_2+ID_6'
120     'ID_100+ID_110'
130     'ID_120+ID_4'
```

This is the simplified version of a formula table with nearly 1000 records and up to 40 levels of reference (items used in other items). The task is breaking down the formulas to just one level reference where no other items are in one item. For example in the table above for id=130 I should have '((ID_3+ID_5)+(ID_2+ID_6))+ID_4'

EDIT: The operations do not limit to "+" and items have a character between them to be recognizable. For the sake of simplicity, I removed that character.

I can use recursive CTE for that. but my problem is that due to high levels of reference, my recursive select has lots of records joining so it takes a lot to complete.

My question is that: Can I keep the previous recursion only each time the recursion happens?

Here is my CTE Code

```
WITH Formula
  AS  (SELECT A.ItemID
             ,'ID_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), A.ItemID) AS ItemText
             ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), A.ItemFormula) AS ItemFormula 
       FROM (VALUES (100,'ID_3+ID_5'),
                    (110,'ID_2+ID_6'),
                    (120,'ID_100+ID_110'),
                    (130,'ID_120+ID_4')   
                ) A (ItemID,ItemFormula)

  )
    ,REC
  AS
      (
          SELECT A.ItemID
                ,A.ItemText
                ,A.ItemFormula
                ,1 AS LevelID
          FROM Formula A
          UNION ALL
          SELECT A.ItemID
                ,A.ItemText
                ,' '
                 + TRIM (REPLACE (REPLACE (A.ItemFormula, B.ItemText, ' ( ' + B.ItemFormula + ' ) '), '  ', ' '))
                 + ' ' AS ItemFormula
                ,A.LevelID + 1 AS LevelID
          FROM REC A
              CROSS APPLY
          (
              SELECT *
              FROM
              (
                  SELECT *
                        ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY GETDATE ()) AS RowNum
                  FROM Formula B2
                  WHERE CHARINDEX (B2.ItemText, A.ItemFormula) > 0
              ) B3
              WHERE B3.RowNum = 1
          ) B
      )
    ,FinalQ
  AS
      (
          SELECT A2.ItemID
                ,A2.ItemFormula
                ,A2.LevelID
          FROM
          (
              SELECT A.ItemID
                    ,REPLACE (TRIM (A.ItemFormula), ' ', '') AS ItemFormula
                    ,A.LevelID
                    ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY A.ItemID ORDER BY A.LevelID DESC) AS RowNum
              FROM REC A
          ) A2
          WHERE A2.RowNum = 1
      )
SELECT * FROM FinalQ A2 ORDER BY A2.ItemID;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Is `+` the only operation allowed?  Can we assume a better format for the references, such as `[ID_1]`?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY GETDATE ())` - This is going to order rows non-deterministicaly, because `GETDATE()` is going to be run once for the entire statement.  Depending on what you need to do, you might have better luck doing this with a stored procedure, or pulling it into a regular application and building the dependency graph.  Or re-architecting the design so you're not parsing the list each time, just resolving an id.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse it is to guarantee that the join only returns one row for the items that have reference to more than one item. so that the items in a formula are processed one by one. since ROW_NUMBER must have an ORDER BY clause, I put it there. the order does not matter here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I answered your question in the EDIT I posted in mine.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that: Can I keep the previous recursion only each time the recursion happens?

No. The recursive CTE will keep adding rows to the ones found in previous iterations. You don't have some kind of control that would allow you to remove rows of the recursive CTE *during* its iterations.

You can, however, filter them out *after* the recursive CTE is complete, maybe on a secondary CTE that takes into account only the last *meaninful* rows (by some kind of rule to be defined).

The only vaguely similar idea is found in PostgreSQL where you can use the `UNION` clause in addition to `UNION ALL`, to avoid producing more identical rows. But this is different to what you need, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is an enormously complicated problem.  Here are the ideas:

1. Find which items do not need any insertions.  These are the ones that have no references to any others.
2. Build an ordering for item insertion.  An insertion can go into an item, assuming that the item is already defined.  A recursive CTE can be used for this.
3. Enumerate the insertions.  Everything from (1) gets a "1".  The rest are in order.
4. Process the insertions in the insertion order.

Here is my solution:

```
with ordering as (
      select itemid, itemtext, itemformula, convert(varchar(max), null) as otheritemtext, 1 as lev
      from formula f
      where not exists (select 1
                        from formula f2 join
                             string_split(f.itemformula, '+') s
                             on f2.itemtext = s.value
                        where f2.itemid <> f.itemid
                       )
       union all
       select f.itemid, f.itemtext, f.itemformula, convert(varchar(max), s.value), lev + 1
       from formula f cross apply
            string_split(f.itemformula, '+') s join
            ordering o
            on o.itemtext = s.value
        -- where lev <= 2
     ),
     ordered as (
      select distinct o.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by (case when lev = 1 then -1 else lev end), (case when lev = 1 then '' else otheritemtext end)) as seqnum
      from ordering o
     ),
     cte as (
      select o.itemid, o.itemtext, o.itemformula, convert(varchar(max), o.otheritemtext) as otheritemtext,
             o.itemformula as newformula, o.seqnum, 1 as lev
      from ordered o
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select cte.itemid, o.itemtext, o.itemformula, convert(varchar(max), cte.itemtext),
             replace(o.itemformula, o.otheritemtext, concat('(', cte.newformula, ')')),  o.seqnum, cte.lev + 1
      from cte join
           ordered o
           on cte.itemtext = o.otheritemtext and cte.seqnum < o.seqnum
     )
select *
from cte;
```

And the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1fa5ebdc6d74d01e5394846ec21b2dba).

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the logical order of the formulas if any (Item_100 can not reference Item_150) and process items in a descending order.
The following uses LIKE and it will not work for formulas which have overlapping patterns (eg ID_10 & ID_100) you could fix that by some string manipulation or by keeping ItemIDs of fixed length (eg. ID_10010 & ID_10100: start numbering of items from a high number like 10000)

```
declare @f table
(
ItemId int,
ItemFormula varchar(1000)
);

insert into @f(ItemId, ItemFormula)
values 
(100, 'ID_3+ID_5'),
(110, 'ID_2+ID_6'),
(120, 'ID_100+ID_110'),
(130, 'ID_120+ID_4'),
(140, '(ID_130+ID_110)/ID_100'),
(150, 'sqrt(ID_140, ID_130)'), 
(160, 'ID_150-ID_120+ID_140');


;with cte
as
(
select f.ItemId, replace(cast(f.ItemFormula as varchar(max)), isnull('ID_' + cast(r.ItemId as varchar(max)), ''), isnull('(' + r.ItemFormula+ ')', '')) as therepl, 1 as lvl
from @f as f
outer apply (
    select *
    from
    (
    select rr.*, row_number() over(order by rr.ItemId desc) as rownum
    from @f as rr
    where f.ItemFormula like '%ID_' + cast(rr.ItemId as varchar(1000)) + '%'
    ) as src
    where rownum = 1
    ) as r
union all
select c.ItemId, replace(c.therepl, 'ID_' + cast(r.ItemId as varchar(max)), '(' + r.ItemFormula+ ')'), c.lvl+1
from cte as c
cross apply (
    select *
    from
    (
    select rr.*, row_number() over(order by rr.ItemId desc) as rownum
    from @f as rr
    where c.therepl like '%ID_' + cast(rr.ItemId as varchar(1000)) + '%'
    ) as src
    where rownum = 1
    ) as r
),
rown
as
(
select *, row_number() over (partition by itemid order by lvl desc) as rownum
from cte
)
select *
from rown
where rownum = 1;
```